# Why doesn't this execute on first click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/RBU8K/

have I the following code

```
function addRemove(id) {
    alert("1");

    $('#'+id).toggle(function() {
    alert("2");
    $('#'+id).after('<tr id="details" ><td>It worked</td></tr>');

    }, function() {
    alert("3");
    $("#details").remove();    
    });
}
```

When clicking one time on "Details" it prints "1", but not "2" for some reason.

When the first click have been done, it works like it is supposed to.

But what's wrong, since the first click doesn't print out "2"?

And how can it be fixed?

**Update**

This is the solution

```
function addRemove(id) {

    if ($('#accTable').find("[id*='details']").length == 0) {   
    $('#'+id).after('<tr id="details" ><td>It worked</td></tr>');
    } else {
    $("table tr").remove("#details");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only attaching a event handler (the toggle thingy) when calling `addRemove()`, then after you click again the event handler gets triggered.

Comment: @Jan Hančič : I would like that when "Details" is clicked a new row `<tr id="details" ><td>It worked</td></tr>` is added right below. When "Details" is clicked again, it should be removed. Ideally only one new row must exist at any time, so if Details is clicked on another row, it should remove the one that already have been added before adding a new.

Comment: what is `Details`? is this button or what?

Comment: @Vivek : Yes, it can be seen in the jsfiddle.

Comment: @Jan Hančič : `$("table tr").remove("#details");` will remove all newly added rows, so that solves the ideal case =)